# Smiling or smiling one?

Tags: word-choice

Smiling or smiling one? ”It turned out that smiling/smiling one is better.” For example, when choosing the best shot from the pictures. English is not my native language, so thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

"It turned out that smiling is better" indicates the *act* of smiling is (was) better. You would want to use "It turned out that smiling *one* is better" to explicitly refer to the photograph.

Answer (score 1):

As the other poster already noted *it turned out that smiling was better* has a different meaning to the the one you want. Smiling here is a participle used like a noun (sometimes called a [Gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)). It is the subject of the 'that-clause' and the sentence means that in general that *the act of smiling is better*.

> It turned out that *the* smiling one was better.

Here 'one' is used as a noun ([pronoun](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/one-and-ones)) and is modified by the participle 'smiling'. It is a particular photo, so you also need the definite article 'the'.